# Amazon Route 53, restrict IAM user access to single record set

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-iam

I would like to programmatically change the CNAME of a Record Set inside an Hosted Zone on Amazon Route 53, but I would like to restrict the access of the user ONLY to that record set. For what I have seen on the documentation IAM allow to specify operation only based on "hosted-zone" or "changes". This means that my user need to have power over ALL my record set to change a single one.

The consequences of an error in the code in a case like this are more than catastrophic. If the checks on the hosted zone name are wrong, for any reason, I could for error apply the changes to more than one record set (imagine many Record Set pointing now on the same box/infrastructure).

My question is not about not making errors in the code, but about creating a user to protect the system from such possibilities. There is a way to restrict access (or a workaround) to allow a new IAM user to access one/a limited set of Hosted Zones only.

On IAM level, not programmatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way you could do this is make a new zone that's a subdomain of the main domain, like `stuff.example.com` and delegate the subdomain's NS to that secondary zone. Give them IAM privileges to that subdomain's zone and they'd be able to create subdomains like `my.stuff.example.com`. For records that you want to be first-class citizens, you could `CNAME` `my.example.com` to `my.stuff.example.com`, which would functionally permit them to manage that subdomain without having full privileges.

Comment: Yes, I agree that probably that is viable. Is a good workaround while I wait for more granular permissions.

Answer (score 7):

I had the chance to ask this question to a couple of aws solutions architect at the last amazon aws conference and they confirmed me is not possible. IAM or better Route53 does not have that level of granularity.

Comment: There is currently planned developments for this feature. This is the last official answer from Amazon: > Thank you for mentioning this, we have raised this with our
> development teams for future consideration.
> > If you have any other suggestions please do let us know.
> > Regards, Davin G. I would suggest you to upvote the related thread at: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=563952&#563952

Answer (score 7):

You can create AWS Lambda function that make this change (only for this single record) and make an invocation policy for this function.